# Component getting unexpectedly unmounted in react-redux app

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

Below is my index.js file of app:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App.js';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

const state = (state = { num: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE':
      return { ...state, num: 2 };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

const store = createStore(combineReducers({ state: state }), applyMiddleware(logger));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Below is App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import A from './A';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  changeNum = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={() => <A changeNum={this.changeNum} />} />
        </Switch>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ num: state.state.num });

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

Below are A.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class A extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.changeNum();
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('A component unmounted');
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>component A</h1>;
  }
}

export default A;
```

The problem is that on hitting '/' route, I see the message `A component unmounted` and two successive `CHANGE` action instead of one in console, which is unexpected.

I have seen such problem in earlier projects as well but I had been ignoring. So I wanted to go down the root of the problem, so here it is.

Please explain me the unexpected behaviour.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax which you are using for rendering the component in `Route` is wrong here . If you want to pass the component some additional props along with the `route` props then you should use `render` instead of `component`

```
 <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <A {...props} changeNum={this.changeNum} />} />
 </Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But why my version was producing this problem? Could you please explain

Comment: what you tried was to render the component as a function . But if you see the way the Route is built . your component prop should not be a function . https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L63 . See this line . If its a component they are doing React.createElement out of it . This will not work in your case because the first argument for the React.createElement has to be a component . But your is a function .